# Cant get ProgressDialog to show up in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progressdialog

I cant get a progress dialog to show when I need it to. I have tried putting it in my asyncTask the ui class and the its own thread that runs on the ui and none have worked. Can anyone help me?

the method where the progressDialog method is called:

```
 public void shareTest(View view){       //method called to jump to share activity if criteria matched

        if(checkInputs()) {                 //call to check inputs
            Share start = new Share();
            boolean isConnected=start.connectToServer();    //connectToServer
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, Share.class); //create intent to move to share class from this activity

            startProgressDialog();
            if (isConnected) {                      //check to see if isconnected was succesful
                if (Share.matchFound ){             //check to see if a match was found
                    progress.dismiss();
                    startActivity(intent);          //if true jump to share activity
                } else {
                    while (!Share.timedOut) {       //While the time has not timedOut
                        if (Share.matchFound) {     //if a share has been found

                            startActivity(intent);  //start share activity
                            break;                  //if true then break
                        }
                    }
                    if (Share.timedOut) {
                        //send an notice that a match wasn't found
                        sendToast(getString(R.string.noShare));                  //if not true then send Toast
                    }
                }
            }
            else sendToast(getString(R.string.errServCon));                       //if connection to server failed then send toast
        }

    }
```

this is the method:

void startProgressDialog() {

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override

        public void run() {     //creates a new runnable thread
            // Issue command() on a separate thread
            while (!Share.matchFound) {       //while havent been asked to disconnect  //if a new location has been recieved
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {     //run on the ui thread act
                            progress.show();        //call the method that does the update
                        }
                    });

            }
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a global variable like this:

```
ProgressDialog progress;
```

Wherever you want to show the progress, paste this code:

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait",
                "Loading..", true);
```

When you are done, simply dismiss it:

```
progress.dismiss();
```

Comment: Yes I have done all this, The progress doesnt start until after match found has been declared false. I have no idea why it does this

Comment: May be you are calling the show() method in the wrong position. Call progress dialog before the execute method of your asynctask or in the preExecute method.